# ROS2: how to run talker-listener from doker-raspberry to docker-pc?

Tags: ros2

I have a raspberry with IP 192.168.0.11. On this raspberry I installed both docker and ROS2 (using docker osrf images).

```
>> sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 192.168.0.0/24
Rules updated
>> sudo ufw allow in proto udp to 192.168.0.0/24
Rules updated
>> sudo docker run -it --rm --name talker ros_docker:latest /bin/bash
root@63a2b3faf54e:/# ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
[INFO] [1699301890.504953398] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[INFO] [1699301891.504865884] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
...
```

I have a PC with IP 192.168.0.13. On this PC I installed both docker and ROS2 (using docker osrf images)

```
>> sudo ufw allow in proto udp to 192.168.0.0/24
Skipping adding existing rule
>> sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 192.168.0.0/24
Skipping adding existing rule
>> sudo docker run -it --rm --name listener osrf/ros:iron-desktop /bin/bash
root@6742d4ebd9f8:/# ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
^C[INFO] [1699302484.895715168] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
```

listener doesn't receive any message even after several minutes. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best and most proper answer, but try adding `--network=host` when you launch both containers. The firewall rules you are creating may be necessary, but they are not sufficient as they do not connect to the docker container. The proper answer is probably to just connect the required UDP ports in the docker container, but I haven't found that documented nicely anywhere.

You can use the `ros2 multicast` tool to test if your communication is working. On one system run `ros2 multicast receive` and on the other `ros2 multicast send`.